# iOS - AppsFlyer Onelink Deeplinking

Tags: appsflyer

`AppsFlyerFramework 4.10.4`
`react-native-appsflyer 1.4.5`
`Testing on iOS 11.3`

When clicking a onelink deep link, I consistently receive the `onInstallConversionDataLoaded` and `onAppOpenAttribution` events, which is great.

However when the app is running in the background, and I click the deep link, no events are fired.

I've gone through the docs but unable to figure this out. https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/208874366-OneLink-deep-linking-guide#deep-linking-data-the-onappopenattribution-method

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that relevant listeners are being registered after SDK is initialised? Also, can it be that they are not being registered in the `_handleAppStateChange` function?
You can read more about this here - https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/react-native-appsflyer/tree/v1.4.1#appsflyeroninstallconversiondatacallback-functionunregister

If that doesn't help to solve the problem, please open a ticket to support@appsflyer.com and we will be more than happy to look into that!